# In MATLAB, For Looping with String Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

A similar question has been asked, but still I'm looking for a solution.

In MATLAB, I have an array of states s:

```
 s = {'Indiana', 'Texas', 'Alabama'}
 Time is a column vector: [120 30 20 40 50]'
 Tornadoes is a column vector: [5 5 3 5 5]'
```

And I need to for loop through this array s for the following code below while placing each string in s in the first line.

```
index = strcmpi(States,s)
Time = Time(index)
Tornadoes = Tornadoes(index)
h = scatter(Time,Tornadoes)
```

So how can I write the code to push each state in s to generate a plot for each plot.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by *"...while placing each string in s in the first line"*. You can loop with `for ii = 1:numel(s) ... end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this?

```
for ii = 1:numel(s)
  index = strcmpi(States, s{ii})
  Time = Time(index)
  Tornadoes = Tornadoes(index)
  figure % make sure you start a new figure each time...
  h = scatter(Time,Tornadoes)
  title(['Tornadoes in ' s{ii}])
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was using a [] instead of {}.

Comment: Cell array... needs the `{}` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to loop through each entry in `s`, you could do

```
j = length(s)
for i = 1:j
    x = Time(i)
    y = Tornadoes(i)
    h = scatter(x, y)
end
```